# How can I find the value of LC_XXX locale integr constants so that I can use them with cffi

Tags: unicode, lisp, common-lisp, ncurses, ffi

I have this code:

```
(define-foreign-library libc
  (:unix "libc.so.6"))
(use-foreign-library libc)
(defcfun "setlocale" :pointer (category :int) (locale :pointer))
```

and I want to do:

```
(with-foreign-string (locale "en_US.UTF-8")
    (setlocale XXXX locale))
```

How can I find the integer values of the various LC_xxx constants so that I can pass them to the call above? Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this in my locale.h:

```
/* These are the possibilities for the first argument to setlocale.
   The code assumes that the lowest LC_* symbol has the value zero.  */
#define LC_CTYPE          __LC_CTYPE
#define LC_NUMERIC        __LC_NUMERIC
#define LC_TIME           __LC_TIME
#define LC_COLLATE        __LC_COLLATE
#define LC_MONETARY       __LC_MONETARY
#define LC_MESSAGES       __LC_MESSAGES
#define LC_ALL            __LC_ALL
#define LC_PAPER          __LC_PAPER
#define LC_NAME           __LC_NAME
#define LC_ADDRESS        __LC_ADDRESS
#define LC_TELEPHONE      __LC_TELEPHONE
#define LC_MEASUREMENT    __LC_MEASUREMENT
#define LC_IDENTIFICATION __LC_IDENTIFICATION
```

and bits/locale.h contains:

```
enum
{
  __LC_CTYPE = 0,
  __LC_NUMERIC = 1,
  __LC_TIME = 2,
  __LC_COLLATE = 3,
  __LC_MONETARY = 4,
  __LC_MESSAGES = 5,
  __LC_ALL = 6,
  __LC_PAPER = 7,
  __LC_NAME = 8,
  __LC_ADDRESS = 9,
  __LC_TELEPHONE = 10,
  __LC_MEASUREMENT = 11,
  __LC_IDENTIFICATION = 12
};
```

You could just compile a C program that prints them.
This is what the groveller does.

Comment: I dont know why I didnt find that second part. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You should re-declare the constants in your Lisp code. In fact, [CFFI can do this for you](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/cffi-manual.html#The-Groveller).

Comment: yes, i know but I must know the values to redeclare them. My problem is that I cant find the values in the whole code of libc. Essentially I m looking for the place the groveller would look to do it. I cant find the headers that contain their values. I would simply like to know where in C code they are declared